# Subgraph Isomorphism with Same Number of Nodes

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, parameterized-complexity, graph-isomorphism

I am looking at a specific variant of subgraph isomorphism:

- **Instance** A graph $G = (V_G, E_G)$ and a target graph $H = (V_H, E_H)$ such that **$|V_G| = |V_H|$**.
- **Question** Is there a subgraph $G' = (V'_G, E'_G)$ of $G$ that is isomorphic to $H$?

(Note the condition $|V_G| = |V_H|$ above, which implies $|V_G| = |V'_G| = |V_H|$)

It is obvious that this variant is $NP$-complete. I am interested in the parameterized complexity of the problem. Is this a known problem? I assume it would be since it is very natural but cannot find any reference for it.

It can equivalently be formulated like this:

- **Instance** A graph $G = (V_G, E_G)$ and a target graph $H = (V_H, E_H)$ such that **$|V_G| = |V_H|$**.
- **Question** Can we reach a graph $G' = (V_G, E'_G)$ by deleting only edges from $G$ such that $G'$ and $H$ are isomorphic?

Also, since I am always working with graphs with the same number of nodes, one could look at them simply as binary relations and not graphs.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: What parameter are you interested in?

Comment: It's not even clear at the moment, standard parameterization consider the number of nodes in $G$ (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06423.pdf for instance), but since graphs have the same size, with that parameter I can go through all mappings in FPT times here...

I am also interested in structural properties of G (treewidth for instance) that would make the problem easy/hard.

Comment: Nearly all variants of subgraph isomorphism are hard for very restricted graph classes. There is a very easy reduction from 3-Partition that shows hardness when $G$ and $H$ are collections of paths (just take paths with lengths corresponding to the numbers). If you want connected graphs you can just add a universal vertex. This shows hardness for treewidth 1 and for connected graphs of treewidth 2, which is tight (connected graphs of treewidth 1 are just trees for which the problem is easy).

Comment: Yes I see thanks for that :) But so it is not a widely studied restriction?